# Как добавить подсказки в VS Code для Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, visual-studio-code

Когда я открываю C# скрипт из Unity, то VS Code при вводе любых слов не выдает подсказки. Например, если я пишу "using Sy", то он должен предложить System, но этого не происходит. Расширение C# установлено, dotnet тоже. VS Code также выбран как основной во вкладке External Tools в Unity.

Comment: [IntelliSense для C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), а вообще какого фига? Вместе с `Unity3D` устанавливается `VS Commander`, а не этот блакнот с поездатым скролбаром на котом текст в минетиатуре... что бы что?

Comment: @Yaroslav чтобы вентилятор тихонечко шуршал, приятно обдувая волосики на ножках. Если серьёзно, эту тряхомудию можно и, пожалуй, нужно отключать.

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в VS Code, заходишь в расширения, ищешь в поиске "Unity", находишь "Unity Tools" от Avin Zarlez, и устанавливает. Ну и все готово, по крайней мере у меня все работает.